# Update text widget onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have a Text  widget where I want to change the text to question and answer variables ontap, but it is not working anyone help.
The question and answer strings are being passed from the previous page.
On this page first it shows the question and when the user tap on that text widget the question have to change to answer text.
But it is not updating don't know why. I am a beginner please help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String question;
  final String answer;
  ShowCard({@required this.question, @required this.answer});     //accepting question and answer

  @override
  _ShowCardState createState() => _ShowCardState();
}


class _ShowCardState extends State<ShowCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    String cardDetails = widget.question;        //initializing question text

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
          child: Text(cardDetails),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (cardDetails == widget.question) {
                cardDetails = widget.answer;
              } else {
                cardDetails = widget.question;
              }
            });
          },
        ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: put this in `initState` instead.   `String cardDetails = widget.question;`

Answer (score 1):

after you tap, the cardDetails is assigned same value again in `build`,

```
String cardDetails = widget.question;
```

Do it like this instead

```
class _ShowCardState extends State<ShowCard> {

  String cardDetails;

  @override
  void initState() {
    cardDetails = widget.question;
    super.initState();
  }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the cardDetails initialization outside of the build function, otherwise, it resets for each build. You can copy the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String question;
  final String answer;
  ShowCard({@required this.question, @required this.answer});     //accepting question and answer

  @override
  _ShowCardState createState() => _ShowCardState();
}


class _ShowCardState extends State<ShowCard> {

String cardDetails = widget.question;        //initializing question text

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
          child: Text(cardDetails),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (cardDetails == widget.question) {
                cardDetails = widget.answer;
              } else {
                cardDetails = widget.question;
              }
            });
          },
        ))),
    );
  }
}
```